# Deleting Duplicate Rows From Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates

Im trying to delete all of the duplicate rows in my datagridview. My data source is from a PHP MySQL database connected with the micron library. I'm using persons id to compare the values which is in cell 5 in each row. This code is in the `Shown()` method of the datagridview. This is what I have so far

```
            for (int i = 1; i < gridBanMusician.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (gridBanMusician.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == removeduplicatecells)
                {
                    gridBanMusician.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    removeduplicatecells = gridBanMusician.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```

My output using this code keeps giving me two of the same rows. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Steven

Comment: Why not filter it in the database call?

Comment: Wouldn't that cause more latency in the program especially for big tables? I thought it was best practice to do it in the code rather than in the sql statement. I'm new at this but that was my understanding.

Comment: I'm new at this but that was my understanding. -- AVOID PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION -- right the query you want that gets the data you want.  Then, if there's an issue with latency,  optimize.   I believe that what you gain (if any) on a simpler query will be lost on the data transfer and the manipulation.  A database is a highly specialized tool designed for querying data.   Your code isn't. (Not a snark, just a fact that specialized tools are better than almost any programmer at their given task).

Comment: Thanks! I redid my query